# Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Toggle

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So I'm trying to create a [spreadsheet](https://goo.gl/lRMqac) to keep track of multiple people and their progress as they complete tasks. On the top of the spreadsheet are toggles. I've used the conditional formatting

```
=RegExMatch($C13,"Not Started")
```

(as an example) to change to a specific color with each project status. I would like the toggles on the top to toggle the conditional formatting on the entire spreadsheet. Is this possible? What formulas would I need?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on the entire spreadsheet"?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach If a toggle is off, then that color will not display on the spreadsheet, simply white background. As if conditional formatting were set to white.

Comment: How about `=AND(RegExMatch($C13,"Not Started"),$A$1="Toggle On")`?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to recreate project management software. Theses types of tools exist in many different forms as web apps. If you're looking for collaborative task tracking, I like web apps like Asana or Azendoo (my personal favorite for teams). If you're looking for kanban-style "not started", "in progress" etc. try an app like Kanbanchi (integrated with google drive) or Trello. My personal philosophy is why recreate the wheel by hand when someone else is mass producing them in a factory. The tools i mentioned above also have some good free options.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Your solution worked, thank you. If you want, you can post your answer on the main thread?

Comment: @Brady Thanks for the input, but this is for a small project for the Civil Air Patrol (think AFJROTC and boy scouts combined). Those services won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle the formatting based on a condition it's enough to include the condition in the formatting rule.
This can be accomplished easiest using `AND()` like this:

```
=AND(RegExMatch($C13,"Not Started"),$A$1="Toggle On")
```